# Python 3.2 won't import cookielib

Tags: python

I have looked everywhere for this and just cannot find the answer. I have checked my python version and it is version 3.2 . When I try to import `cookielib` I receive:

`ImportError: No module named cookielib`

I have seen that in Python 3.0 it was renamed to 
`http.cookiejar` and that it would auto import `cookielib`.

I thought that maybe there was some wild error in my python configuration so I thought I should try and import `http.cookiejar` like this `import http.cookiejar`. That did not work all and I get and error:

 `EOFError: EOF read where not expected`.

This is not the error I had expected becuase `import http.cookies` imports just fine. 

Does anybody have a solution to this problem? What am I overlooking?

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Downloads\selenium-2.20.0.tar\selenium-2.20.0\selenium-2.20.0\test", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, http.cookiejar
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *automatic renaming* business only applies if you use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-to3). Therefore, you have to `import http.cookiejar`.

The error `EOFError: EOF read where not expected` is only ever thrown by Python marshalling. Most likely, this is caused by a race condition [fixed in Python 3.3](http://bugs.python.org/issue13146), where multiple processes tried to write concurrently to the pyc file. Deleting all .pyc files may be a workaround.

Comment: For those who come across this in the future: reinstalling Python seems like a drastic step. Just deleting the `.pyc` files from whatever library is causing the `EOFError` was sufficient for me just now.

Comment: The EOFError: is most likely a race condition when 3 or more Python processes read/write the same pyc file. Fixed in Python 3.3: http://bugs.python.org/issue13146

Comment: @GuidovanRossum Thanks for the pointer! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
try:
    import cookielib
except:
    import http.cookiejar
    cookielib = http.cookiejar
```

Answer (score 4):

The `cookielib` module has been renamed to `http.cookiejar` in Python 3.0. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3.0.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you presented one or two short examples.

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess is that you have a corrupted library file. Inside your Python installation, look at `lib/python3.2/http/cookiejar.py` and scroll down to the end. Mine (Python 3.2.2) ends in the `save()` method definition with

```
finally:
    f.close()
```

If you see anything else, your installation is probably broken and I'd recommend reinstalling it.