# How to save requests (python) cookies to a file?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

How to use the library `requests` (in python) after a request

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
bot = requests.session()
bot.get('http://google.com')
```

to keep all the cookies in a file and then restore the cookies from a file.

Answer (score 97):

There is no immediate way to do so, but it's not hard to do.

You can get a `CookieJar` object from the session with `session.cookies`, and use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to store it to a file.

A full example:

```
import requests, pickle
session = requests.session()
# Make some calls
with open('somefile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(session.cookies, f)
```

Loading is then:

```
session = requests.session()  # or an existing session

with open('somefile', 'rb') as f:
    session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))
```

The `requests` library uses the [`requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()` subclass](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar), which explicitly supports pickling and a dict-like API. The [`RequestsCookieJar.update()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar.update) can be used to update an existing session cookie jar with the cookies loaded from the pickle file.

Comment: `requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar` and `requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict` are not required. They don't save cookies with the same name for different domains and don't save all the required cookies data. I spent a lot of time debugging just because of these.

Comment: pickling a cookiejar doesn't seem to save the host that its associated with.  when you load again all cookies are just in the host ''.

Comment: @MattClimbs, it is `dict_from_cookiejar` which doesn't save host information. Actually, in current version `session.cookies` can be pickled and unpickled directly, without converting to `dict`.
Also, `requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar` can be replaced with `session.cookies.get_dict()`, and `cookiejar_from_dict` can be replaced with `session.cookies.update(my_dict)`.

Comment: *Editors note*: I've updated this top answer rather than add a new post. It was close enough but needed updating for API changes made in the intervening 6 years that make this task all that much easier. Do not use the dictionary utilities, they are not needed at all and do not preserve important cookie medatada. I'm fine with posting my own answer if the author wishes to revert my changes; I'd appreciate a heads-up in that case.

Comment: In my case (a python newbie), after `open() as f`, there should be a `f.close()`. Otherwise two consecutive `open()` would rise "TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects".

Comment: @Weekend, you don't need to explicitly call `f.close()` when using the `with` statement. The _context manager_ implicitly calls `f.close()` for you. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files The 2 separate `with` statements in the answer are not nested.

Answer (score 38):

After a call such as `r = requests.get()`, `r.cookies` will return a `RequestsCookieJar` which you can directly [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), i.e.

```
import pickle
def save_cookies(requests_cookiejar, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(requests_cookiejar, f)

def load_cookies(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

#save cookies
r = requests.get(url)
save_cookies(r.cookies, filename)

#load cookies and do a request
requests.get(url, cookies=load_cookies(filename))
```

If you want to save your cookies in human-readable format, you have to do some work to extract the `RequestsCookieJar` to a [`LWPCookieJar`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.LWPCookieJar).

```
import cookielib
def save_cookies_lwp(cookiejar, filename):
    lwp_cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    for c in cookiejar:
        args = dict(vars(c).items())
        args['rest'] = args['_rest']
        del args['_rest']
        c = cookielib.Cookie(**args)
        lwp_cookiejar.set_cookie(c)
    lwp_cookiejar.save(filename, ignore_discard=True)

def load_cookies_from_lwp(filename):
    lwp_cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    lwp_cookiejar.load(filename, ignore_discard=True)
    return lwp_cookiejar

#save human-readable
r = requests.get(url)
save_cookies_lwp(r.cookies, filename)

#you can pass a LWPCookieJar directly to requests
requests.get(url, cookies=load_cookies_from_lwp(filename))
```

Comment: `all(isinstance(c, cookielib.Cookie) for c in r.cookies)` is `True`, so why created each cookie item again in `save_cookies_lwp`?

Comment: Please use a session in your answer

Answer (score 28):

I offer a way by json:

to save cookie -

```
import json
with open('cookie.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(bot.cookies), f)
```

and to load cookie -

```
import json
session = requests.session()  # or an existing session

with open('cookie.txt', 'r') as f:
    cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(json.load(f))
    session.cookies.update(cookies)
```

Comment: requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar <-- exactly what I wanted

Comment: Note that `dict_from_cookiejar` loses host information and hence does not work if there are several cookies with same name for different hosts.

Comment: This should have been best answer - no external libs which are not included by default.

Comment: this is not correct, dict_from_cookiejar loses many informations about cookies.

Comment: You will lose many information (such as host,) if you use this.

Answer (score 25):

Expanding on @miracle2k's answer, requests `Session`s are [documented](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#sessionapi) to work with any [cookielib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.CookieJar) `CookieJar`. The `LWPCookieJar` (and `MozillaCookieJar`) can save and load their cookies to and from a file. Here is a complete code snippet which will save and load cookies for a requests session. The `ignore_discard` parameter is used to work with httpbin for the test, but you may not want to include it your in real code.

```
import os
from cookielib import LWPCookieJar

import requests


s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = LWPCookieJar('cookiejar')
if not os.path.exists('cookiejar'):
    # Create a new cookies file and set our Session's cookies
    print('setting cookies')
    s.cookies.save()
    r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?k1=v1&k2=v2')
else:
    # Load saved cookies from the file and use them in a request
    print('loading saved cookies')
    s.cookies.load(ignore_discard=True)
    r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')
print(r.text)
# Save the session's cookies back to the file
s.cookies.save(ignore_discard=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

I found that the other answers had problems:

- They didn't apply to sessions.
- They didn't save and load properly.  Only the cookie name and value was saved, the expiry date, domain name, etc. was all lost.

This answer fixes these two issues:

```
import requests.cookies

def save_cookies(session, filename):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(filename)):
        return False
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.truncate()
        pickle.dump(session.cookies._cookies, f)


def load_cookies(session, filename):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return False

    with open(filename) as f:
        cookies = pickle.load(f)
        if cookies:
            jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
            jar._cookies = cookies
            session.cookies = jar
        else:
            return False
```

Then just call `save_cookies(session, filename)` to save or `load_cookies(session, filename)` to load.  Simple as that.

Comment: This worked for me without the os.path.isdir lines in each function. Calling open() creates the file if it doesn't exist, and writes correctly for my use-case.

Comment: This works well, but needs a small update for Python 3.  Pickling creates binary data, so the open calls should be: open(filename, "wb") and open(filename, "rb") respectively.

Answer (score 9):

This will do the job:

```
session.cookies = LWPCookieJar('cookies.txt')
```

The CookieJar API requires you to call load() and save() manually though. If you do not care about the cookies.txt format, I have a [ShelvedCookieJar](https://github.com/miracle2k/track0/blob/master/track/utils.py#L8) implementation that will persist on change.

Comment: This answer is missing a few steps. Here is the full code: `cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar(cookie_file)` `cj.load()` `session.cookies = cj`

Comment: I tried using ShelvedCookieJar, but I found that the results don't get flushed to the disk unless `jar.shelf.close()` is called and the jar isn't usable after `jar.shelf.close()` is called, so managing the lifecycle of the jar is not straightforward.

Answer (score 7):

**code for python 3**

Note that the great majority of cookies on the Internet are Netscape cookies. so if you want to save cookies to disk in the Mozilla cookies.txt file format (which is also used by the Lynx and Netscape browsers) use MozillaCookieJar

```
from http.cookiejar import MozillaCookieJar
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = MozillaCookieJar('cookies.txt')
# or s.cookies = MozillaCookieJar() and later use s.cookies.filename = 'cookies.txt' or pass the file name to save method.

response = s.get('https://www.msn.com')

s.cookies.save()
```

the file is overwritten if it already exists, thus wiping all the cookies it contains. Saved cookies can be restored later using the load() or revert() methods.

> Note that the save() method won’t save session cookies anyway, unless
>   you ask otherwise by passing a true ignore_discard argument.

```
s.cookies.save(ignore_discard=True)
```

**using load method:**

load cookies from a file.

Old cookies are kept unless overwritten by newly loaded ones.

```
s.cookies.load()
```

**using revert method:**

Clear all cookies and reload cookies from a saved file.

```
s.cookies.revert()
```

you may need also to pass a true ignore_discard argument in load or revert methods.

**note about using MozillaCookieJar :**

> Note This loses information about RFC 2965 cookies, and also about
>   newer or non-standard cookie-attributes such as port.

[more reading](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.cookiejar.html?highlight=mozillacookiejar#module-http.cookiejar)

Comment: This basically works fine, but you cannot add/update cookies like you can with `requests.update()`.

Comment: How do I convert a `RequestsCookieJar` to a `MozillaCookieJar` so that I can save it in that format?

Answer (score 5):

Simple way to convert cookies into list of dicts and save to json or db.
This is methods of class which have `session` attribute.

```
def dump_cookies(self):
    cookies = []
    for c in self.session.cookies:
        cookies.append({
            "name": c.name,
            "value": c.value,
            "domain": c.domain,
            "path": c.path,
            "expires": c.expires
        })
    return cookies

def load_cookies(self, cookies):
    for c in cookies:
        self.session.cookies.set(**c)
```

All we need is five parameters such as: `name`, `value`, `domain`, `path`, `expires`

Answer (score 4):

You can pickle the cookies object directly:

```
cookies = pickle.dumps(session.cookies)
```

The dict representation misses a lot of informations: expiration, domain, path...

It depends on the usage you intend to do with the cookies, but if you don't have informations about the expiration, for example, you should implement the logic to track expiration by hand.

Pickling the library returned object lets you easily reconstruct the state, then you can relay on the library implementation.

Obviously, this way, the consumer of the pickled object needs to use the same library

Answer (score 2):

dtheodor's answer got 95% there, except this:

```
session = requests.session(cookies=cookies)
```

For me this raises an exception saying session() does not takes arguments.

I worked around it by taking the keys/values on the cookie.get_dict and adding them manually to the session using:

```
session.cookies.set(cookies.keys()[n],cookies.values()[n])
```

Comment: using `session.cookies.set(cookies.keys()[n],cookies.values()[n])` worked for me as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For all the solutions that use Cookielib, in Python 3.0 its been changed to http.cookiejar
Please lookup [Python 3.2 won't import cookielib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857677/python-3-2-wont-import-cookielib/44894126)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @miracle2k answer, I implemented [jaraco.net.http.cookies.ShelvedCookieJar](https://jaraconet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#jaraco.net.http.cookies.ShelvedCookieJar). I started out using the same `shelve.Shelf`-backed store, but later found that interface to be insufficiently portable and inspectable, so I created a bespoke `Shelf` class backed by [jsonpickle](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpickle). This approach has nice portability and concurrency behaviors but also transparency (the filename is inspectable and the cookies file is human and machine readable). Usage is trivially simple:

```py
from jaraco.net.http.cookies import ShelvedCookieJar

session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = ShelvedCookieJar.create()
```

Thereafter, cookies are persisted in `./cookies.json`. No manual management of when to persist values. No manual opening of files. Simply create and use.