# How to send a cookie with requests.get or requests.post in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having a really hard time converting the following bash script to python

The following works:

```
USERNAME=username
PASSWORD=password
COOKIE_FILE=app_cookies
echo $COOKIE_FILE
res=`curl -s -L -c $COOKIE_FILE -b $COOKIE_FILE -d "j_username=$USERNAME&j_password=$PASSWORD" http://localhost:8080/j_security_check | grep "Authenticated" | wc -l`
if [ $res -gt 0 ]; then
    echo $COOKIE_FILE
    curl -b $COOKIE_FILE http://localhost:8080/data
fi
rm -f $COOKIE_FILE
```

Now in Python, I'm not sure how to complete the cookies part

```
COOKIE_FILE="app_cookies"
USERNAME=username
PASSWORD=password
result = os.system("curl -s -L -c " + COOKIE_FILE + " -b " + COOKIE_FILE + " -d \"j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password 
                    + "\" http://localhost:8080/j_security_check | grep \"Authenticated\" | wc -l")
# Authenticated
if result == 0:
    # it reaches here fine
    cookies = ????
    response = requests.get(url='http://localhost:8080/data', 
                        cookies=?????)
    print response.status_code
    print response.text
```

Comment: In your Python script, is there a reason why you are using `curl` for the first call but then use `requests.get` for the second? Why not use `curl` for both, since it seems to work? Also I believe `subprocess.Popen()` is a better way to invoke CLI commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Python for your first call. This will be much easier and take the advantages of python. It's not tested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
session = requests.session()
payload = {'j_username': username, 'j_password': password}
r = session.post(url='http://localhost:8080/j_security_check', data=payload)

if u"Authenticated" in r.text:
    data = session.get(url='http://localhost:8080/data')
    print data, data.text
```

If you want the cookie to persist look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030095/how-to-save-requests-python-cookies-to-a-file).

Comment: thank you! the if passes, I added a print statement, when I print r.cookies I get <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>

Comment: running the bash script creates the file and in it there is some text with workerthmrgrvlujxfx9b2bk5lg6ap

Comment: You're welcome. So the second call isn't working correctly? I have edited my post so with a session it should work now.

Comment: PERFECT, you saved my life

Comment: Beware of requests sent to `localhost` and session cookies. If a web server returns `localhost` in the domain property of a cookie, such cookie will be rejected. The correct domain property value should be `localhost.local`. It is better to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`