# Struggling to retrieve csrf token from a cookiejar object

Tags: python, cookies, csrf, cookiejar

I am using the code below based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858635/908703) to store authentication cookies in a file. This allows me to avoid having to log in every time I run the program.

Now, fetching the **csrftoken** from regular Session cookies works well, but when I try to fetch it from the cookiejar using `csrf = s.cookies['csrftoken']`, I get

```
AttributeError: LWPCookieJar instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`
```

I understand that this happens because I treat s.cookies as a list even though is now a LWPCookieJar object. I suppose this leaves me with two options:

Either:

- Extract the list from the `LWPCookieJar` object and then getting the csrf token is easy.
- or, Find the appropriate syntax to retrieve the csrf token directly from the `LWPCookieJar`.

How can I do this?

---

```
import os
import requests
from cookielib import LWPCookieJar

s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = LWPCookieJar('cookiejar')
if os.path.exists('cookiejar'):
    # Load saved cookies from the file and use them in a request
    print('loading saved cookies')
    s.cookies.load()        
else:
    # Create a new cookies file and set our Session's cookies
    print('saving cookies')
    s.cookies.save()
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')
print(r.text)
# Save the session's cookies back to the file
s.cookies.save()
```

Comment: Can you run `dir(s.cookies)`?

Comment: @IanAuld: yes. It returns a very long list.

Comment: Well that list contains all the attributes and methods attaches to that object. Is there one in there that sounds like it will do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Not sure if it can be further simplified.

```
import os, requests
from cookielib import LWPCookieJar

def login():
    global s
    s = requests.Session()
    if os.path.exists('cookiejar'):
        print('Cookies exist! Fast login.\r'),
        global csrf
        with open('cookiejar') as f:
            s.cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(pickle.load(f))
        csrf = s.cookies['csrftoken']
        print('csrf: {0}').format(csrf) # Debug information
    else:
        print('Cookies do not exist. Slow login.\r'),
        s.get('http://www.example.com/') # to get csrf
        csrf = s.cookies['csrftoken']
        data= dict(csrftoken=csrf, username="user", password="pass")
        s.post('https://www.example.com/login/', data=data, headers=headers)
        with open('cookiejar', 'w') as f:
            pickle.dump(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(s.cookies), f)
```