# How can I use cookies in Python Requests?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to log in to a page and access another link in the page.

I get a "405 Not Allowed" error from this attempt:

```
payload={'username'=<username>,'password'=<password>}
with session() as s:
    r = c.post(<URL>, data=payload)
    print(r)
    print(r.content)
```

I checked the post method details using Chrome developer tools and found a URL that appeard to be an API endpoint. I posted to that URL with the payload and it seemed to work; I got a response similar to what I could see in the developer.

Unfortunately, when trying to 'get' another URL after logging in, I am still getting the content from the login page.
Why is the login not sticking? Should I use cookies? How?

Answer (score 170):

You can use a session object. It stores the cookies so you can make requests, and it handles the cookies for you

```
s = requests.Session() 
# all cookies received will be stored in the session object

s.post('http://www...',data=payload)
s.get('http://www...')
```

Docs: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

You can also save the cookie data to an external file, and then reload them to keep session persistent without having to login every time you run the script:

[How to save requests (python) cookies to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030095/how-to-save-requests-python-cookies-to-a-file)

Comment: :O This is amazing! I wish I had known about this feature before.
Is it storing the cookies on disk like a browser, or just holding them in memory?

Comment: It just keeps them in memory while the application is running. To save/load cookies from disk see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441145/4411196

Comment: I instead of saving them, made a global variable assigned it a session and made a function so it logins if the cookie is not there and/or returns the session

Comment: for me print(s.cookies) shows that cookies are in the session but are not always passed in subsequent requests (in fact the same code works against localhost but against a test server does not)

Answer (score 101):

From the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies):

1. get cookie from response

   ```
    url = 'http://example.com/some/cookie/setting/url'
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.cookies
   ```

   `{'example_cookie_name': 'example_cookie_value'}`
2. give cookie back to server on subsequent request

   ```
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies'
    cookies = {'cookies_are': 'working'}
    r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)`
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it seems there are no cookies that getting created. I checked the request headers and could not see any 'cookies'. Meanwhile there is one cookie created in response headers. How can i make my login stick if there is no cookie.

Comment: The normal flow for an authentication cookie is: (1) when you submit a login form, you receive a cookie in the response headers. (2) on subsequent page requests, you add the cookie to the request headers.

Comment: how do you add multiple cookies ?

Comment: The kwarg “cookies” is a dict, you can add as many items as you want.

Answer (score 19):

Summary (@Freek Wiekmeijer, @gtalarico) other's answer:

### Logic of Login

- Many resource(pages, api) need `authentication`, then can access, otherwise `405 Not Allowed`
- Common `authentication`=`grant access` method are:

  - `cookie`
  - `auth header`

    - `Basic xxx`
    - `Authorization xxx`

### How use `cookie` in `requests` to auth

1. first get/generate cookie
2. send cookie for following request

- manual set `cookie` in `headers`
- auto process `cookie` by `requests`'s

  - `session` to auto manage cookies
  - `response.cookies` to manually set cookies

#### use `requests`'s `session` auto manage cookies

```py
curSession = requests.Session() 
# all cookies received will be stored in the session object

payload={'username': "yourName",'password': "yourPassword"}
curSession.post(firstUrl, data=payload)
# internally return your expected cookies, can use for following auth

# internally use previously generated cookies, can access the resources
curSession.get(secondUrl)

curSession.get(thirdUrl)
```

#### manually control `requests`'s `response.cookies`

```py
payload={'username': "yourName",'password': "yourPassword"}
resp1 = requests.post(firstUrl, data=payload)

# manually pass previously returned cookies into following request
resp2 = requests.get(secondUrl, cookies= resp1.cookies)

resp3 = requests.get(thirdUrl, cookies= resp2.cookies)
```

Answer (score 6):

As others noted, Here is an example of how to add cookies as string variable to the headers parameter -

```py
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) ...",
    "cookie": "_fbp=fb.1.1654447470850.2143140577; _ga=GA1.2.1...",
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```