# Using Python to login to a website and web scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The web page I need to scrape for data is after a login page. I have tried numerous methods to accomplish this but none seem to work. Can someone help? My code is below...

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {                                                               
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
                  AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}
login_data = {                                                                
    'appname': 'unknown',
    'appversion': 'unknown',
    'ostype': 'mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 
              (khtml, like gecko) chrome/70.0.3538.110 safari/537.36',
    'type': 'null',
    'ssobypass': 'true',
    'dirlogin': 'true',
    'inch': 'true',
    'scrWidth': '1920',
    'scrHeight': '1040',
    'username': 'TA_KAITM_B_4a',
    'userpassword': ''}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "http://cmis.ittdublin.ie"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

It will not allow me to add the HTML of the log in screen here...
Below is code, if run will return the HTML of the login page...

```
import requests
from lxml import html

session_requests = requests.session()
login_url = "http://cmis.ittdublin.ie/eportal/index.jsp"
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
payload = {
    "username": "TA_KAITM_B_4a"
}
result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = payload, 
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)
print(result.text)
url = 'http://cmis.ittdublin.ie/eportal/index.jsp'
result = session_requests.get(
    url, 
    headers = dict(referer = url)
)
```

Comment: Please share the html code of `http://cmis.ittdublin.ie` after login.

Comment: You need to analyse how the site retains login state.  Look at things like cookies and data in the response.  Once you've gathered that, you have to copy some portions to later requests for the actual content.

Comment: It only returns html code of login screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use cookies in Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554771/how-to-use-cookies-in-python-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you need to post to is

```
http://cmis.ittdublin.ie/eportal/PortalServ?reqtype=login
```

I'm optimistic this with get you in. Whether or not it lands you somewhere useful depends upon what setAdminLoginLocation() does, but perhaps it does nothing except with an administrator login.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked!