# add a cookie to requests session

Tags: python, session, cookies

I want to start a `requests.Session()` and add a cookie before starting the first request. I expected to have a cookie argument or something similar to do this

```
def session_start()
    self.session = requests.Session(cookies=['session-id', 'xxx'])

def req1():
    self.session.get('example.org')

def req2():
    self.session.get('example2.org')
```

but this wont work, I only can provide `cookies` in the `.get()` method. Do I need to do a "dummy request" in session_start() or is there a way to prepare the cookie before starting the actual request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use cookies in Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554771/how-to-use-cookies-in-python-requests)

Comment: no not really, I have a session ID from a login that I want to use again, but I want to set it when I create the session with requests.Session(), not only when I do the first request

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/):

Note, however, that method-level parameters will not be persisted across requests, even if using a session. This example will only send the cookies with the first request, but not the second:

```py
s = requests.Session()

r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies', cookies={'from-my': 'browser'})
print(r.text)
# '{"cookies": {"from-my": "browser"}}'

r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies')
print(r.text)
# '{"cookies": {}}'
```

Comment: ok thats not really an answer to my problem :) and anyway, this shouldn't be a problem, because my response will again return the session cookie

Answer (score 3):

`session.cookies` is a [RequestsCookieJar](https://requests11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar) and you can add cookies to that after constructing the session:

```
self.session = requests.Session()
self.session.cookies.set('session-id', 'xxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

So session objects will persist any cookies that the url requests themselves set, but if you provide a cookie as an argument it will *not* persist on the next request.

You can add cookies in manually that persist too though, from the documentation:
"If you want to manually add cookies to your session, use the Cookie utility functions to manipulate Session.cookies."
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Where it links to on how to manipulate cookies: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#api-cookies