# Python requests - session token changing

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently using Python requests to scrape data from a website and using Postman as a tool to help me do it.

To those not familiar with Postman, it sends a get request and generates a code snippet to be used in many languages, including Python.

By using it, I can get data from the website quite easily, but it seems as like the 'Cookie' aspect of headers provided by Postman changes with time, so I can't automate my code to run anytime. The issue is that when the cookie is not valid I get an access denied message.

Here's an example of the code provided by Postman:

```
import requests

url = "https://wsloja.ifood.com.br/ifood-ws-v3/restaurants/7c854a4c-01a4-48d8-b3d4-239c6c069f6a/menu"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'access_key': '69f181d5-0046-4221-b7b2-deef62bd60d5',
  'browser': 'Windows',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'secret_key': '9ef4fb4f-7a1d-4e0d-a9b1-9b82873297d8',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store',
  'X-Ifood-Session-Id': '85956739-2fac-4ebf-85d3-1aceda9738df',
  'platform': 'Desktop',
  'app_version': '8.37.0',
  'Cookie': 'session_token=TlNUXzMyMjJfMTU5Nzg1MDE5NTIxNF84NDI5NTA2NDQ2MjUxMg==; _abck=AD1745CB8A0963BF3DD67C8AF7932007~-1~YAAQtXsGYH8UUe9zAQAACZ+IAgStbP4nYLMtonPvQ+4UY+iHA3k6XctPbGQmPF18spdWlGiDB4/HbBvDiF0jbgZmr2ETL8YF+f71Uwhsj+L8K+Fk4PFWBolAffkIRDfSubrf/tZOYRfmw09o59aFuQor5LeqxzXkfVsXE8uIJE0P/nC1JfImZ35G0OFt+HyIgDUZMFQ54Wnbap7+LMSWcvMKF6U/RlLm46ybnNnT/l/NLRaEAOIeIE3/JdKVVcYT2t4uePfrTkr5eD499nyhFJCwSVQytS9P7ZNAM4rFIPnM6kPtwcPjolLNeeU=~-1~-1~-1; ak_bmsc=129F92B2F8AC14A400433647B8C29EA3C9063145805E0000DB253D5F49CE7151~plVgguVnRQTAstyzs8P89cFlKQnC9ISQCH9KPHa8xYPDVoV2iQ/Hij2PL9r8EKEqcQfzkGmUWpK09ZpU0tL/llmBloi+S+Znl5P5/NJeV6Ex2gXqBu1ZCxc9soMWWyrdvG+0FFvSP3a6h3gaouPh2O/Tm4Ghk9ddR92t380WBkxvjXBpiPzoYp1DCO4yrEsn3Tip1Gan43IUHuCvO+zkRmgrE3Prfl1T/g0Px9mvLSVrg=; bm_sz=3106E71C2F26305AE435A7DA00506F01~YAAQRTEGyfky691zAQAAGuDbBggFW4fJcnF1UtgEsoXMFkEZk1rG8JMddyrxP3WleKrWBY7jA/Q08btQE43cKWmQ2qtGdB+ryPtI2KLNqQtKM5LnWRzU+RqBQqVbZKh/Rvp2pfTvf5lBO0FRCvESmYjeGvIbnntzaKvLQiDLO3kZnqmMqdyxcG1f51aoOasrjfo=; bm_sv=B4011FABDD7E457DDA32CBAB588CE882~aVOIuceCgWY25bT2YyltUzGUS3z5Ns7gJ3j30i/KuVUgG1coWzGavUdKU7RfSJewTvE47IPiLztXFBd+mj7c9U/IJp+hIa3c4z7fp22WX22YDI7ny3JxN73IUoagS1yQsyKMuxzxZOU9NpcIl/Eq8QkcycBvh2KZhhIZE5LnpFM='
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Here's just the Cookie part where I get access denied:

```
        'Cookie': 'session_token=TlNUXzMyMjJfMTU5Nzg1MDE5NTIxNF84NDI5NTA2NDQ2MjUxMg==; _abck=AD1745CB8A0963BF3DD67C8AF7932007~-1~YAAQtXsGYH8UUe9zAQAACZ+IAgStbP4nYLMtonPvQ+4UY+iHA3k6XctPbGQmPF18spdWlGiDB4/HbBvDiF0jbgZmr2ETL8YF+f71Uwhsj+L8K+Fk4PFWBolAffkIRDfSubrf/tZOYRfmw09o59aFuQor5LeqxzXkfVsXE8uIJE0P/nC1JfImZ35G0OFt+HyIgDUZMFQ54Wnbap7+LMSWcvMKF6U/RlLm46ybnNnT/l/NLRaEAOIeIE3/JdKVVcYT2t4uePfrTkr5eD499nyhFJCwSVQytS9P7ZNAM4rFIPnM6kPtwcPjolLNeeU=~-1~-1~-1; ak_bmsc=129F92B2F8AC14A400433647B8C29EA3C9063145805E0000DB253D5F49CE7151~plVgguVnRQTAstyzs8P89cFlKQnC9ISQCH9KPHa8xYPDVoV2iQ/Hij2PL9r8EKEqcQfzkGmUWpK09ZpU0tL/llmBloi+S+Znl5P5/NJeV6Ex2gXqBu1ZCxc9soMWWyrdvG+0FFvSP3a6h3gaouPh2O/Tm4Ghk9ddR92t380WBkxvjXBpiPzoYp1DCO4yrEsn3Tip1Gan43IUHuCvO+zkRmgrE3Prfl1T/g0Px9mvLSVrg=; bm_sz=3106E71C2F26305AE435A7DA00506F01~YAAQRTEGyfky691zAQAAGuDbBggFW4fJcnF1UtgEsoXMFkEZk1rG8JMddyrxP3WleKrWBY7jA/Q08btQE43cKWmQ2qtGdB+ryPtI2KLNqQtKM5LnWRzU+RqBQqVbZKh/Rvp2pfTvf5lBO0FRCvESmYjeGvIbnntzaKvLQiDLO3kZnqmMqdyxcG1f51aoOasrjfo=; bm_sv=B4011FABDD7E457DDA32CBAB588CE882~aVOIuceCgWY25bT2YyltUzGUS3z5Ns7gJ3j30i/KuVUgG1coWzGavUdKU7RfSJewTvE47IPiLztXFBd+mj7c9U/IJp+hIa3c4z7fp22WX23E755znZL76c0V/amxbHU9BUnrEff3HGcsniyh5mU+C9XVmtNRLd8oT1UW9WUg3qE='    }
```

Which is slightly different from the one before.

How could I get through this by somehow having python get the session token?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31571805/2738151) solve your question?

Comment: It does not, Hernán. I am still getting access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently just removing 'Cookie' from headers does the job.