# How to scrape data using my cookies to automatically login?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am wondering how I could scrape data from a website that requires my login, and login automatically using cookies so I won't get blocked by verification when I try to login with a username and a password.

For example,
I have a channel in discord that can only be viewed if I am logged in on my account.

```
url = https://discord.com/channels/742886974288822413/743510591670583306
```

Is there any way I could send a request to this website and put my cookies in as an argument so I am logged in by default when I am scraping this site? I despise using selenium as it is very slow, and opens up an entire browser on my system. I would prefer using a tool that doesn't open up an entire browser, such as the requests module or urllib.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use cookies in Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554771/how-to-use-cookies-in-python-requests)

Comment: Sort of but I am confused what it means by payload what should that variable be equal to?

Comment: @biomiker would the login be to my discord account or google account when it says: `payload={'username'=<username>,'password'=<password>}`?

Comment: @biomiker The payload above is invalid syntax on my pycharm I think that answer is outdated.

Comment: I am so confused nothing makes sense what code what I use to scrape the data from that website, and how would I send the request using the cookies from my default chrome browser?

Comment: Sorry, payload is the content that is being posted in that example.  You only need to do a GET operation so you wouldn't need to submit a payload.  However, I assumed from your question that you can submit your credentials using only a cookie.  Do you know if that's the case or not?

Comment: I am not sure which credentials to post.

Comment: So which code would I execute and where would I type my credentials?

Comment: That's a different question.   It depends on the manner in which the website authenticates.  However, I think you should abandon the idea of trying to scrape the web interface and look into discord's developer portal instead.  
https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro