# Python read Cookies from response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, session, python-requests

In python I have:

```
cookies = dict(PHPSESSID='PHPSESSID=djsgkjhsdjkhj34',
               authchallenge='sdifhshdfiuh34234234',
               rishum='skdhfuihuisdhf-' + '10403111')

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
```

But I'm looking to use cookies value for the **first time only** and then use the new ones the server sets, how can I do that?

the solutions I found don't use default cookies for first request.

**Note:** I can't login automatically to the website since it uses auth challenge so everytime I login manually and change those cookies only for first request and then when the server updates them I want to see this affects my current cookies.

---

**Example of how my website works:**

At first I login using recaptcha and then get temp cookies,

for the first request in my app I want to use these temp cookies (already know them)

later, which each request I need to use the cookies from the previous response (they change with each request)

My current code:

```
def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:
        keep_running = execute_data()
        time.sleep(5.0 - ((time.time() - start_time) % 5.0))


def execute_data():
    url = 'https:me.happ.com/rishum/register/confirm'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.16; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Connection': 'close'
    }

    cookies = dict(rishum='dsfsdf21312zxcasd-' + '39480523')

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
```

Comment: Note: I saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31571805 but the problem is that I want to use my own cookies for the first time only and then update them according to the server's response

Comment: Added more information that may help

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it but are a bit off on your dictionary implementation.

This is what you are looking for:

```py
cookies = {
    "PHPSESSID": "djsgkjhsdjkhj34",
    "authchallenge" : "sdifhshdfiuh34234234",
    "rishum": 'skdhfuihuisdhf-' + '10403111'
    }

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
```

**Edit:** I see now that this isn't the issue but that you want to update cookies during a session, here is a simple example of how to do so with **requests.Session**:

```py
from requests import Session

s = Session()

s.cookies["foo"] = "bar"

r = s.get('https://google.com')

print("Before:")
for cookie in s.cookies:
    print(cookie)

print()

s.cookies["bo"] = "baz"
print("After: ")
for cookie in s.cookies:
    print(cookie)
```

**Edit #2:**

To further answer your question, here is a better example of how you can update cookies(all of them, if needed) in a loop.

```py
from requests import Session, cookies

s = Session()

b = s.get('https://google.com')

for cookie in s.cookies:
    print(cookie.value)


# Iterate over cookies
for cookie in s.cookies:

    # You can see we already have this cookie's info in the $cookie variable so lets delete it from the cookie jar
    del s.cookies[cookie.name]
    
    # You can update the values HERE
    # ...
    # Example:
    cookieValue = cookie.value.upper()

    # Then save the new cookie to the cookie jar.
    updated_cookie = cookies.create_cookie(domain=cookie.domain,name=cookie.name,value=cookieValue)
    s.cookies.set_cookie(updated_cookie)

for cookie in s.cookies:
    print(cookie.value)
```

Comment: cookies=cookies won't that always use the default cookies?

Comment: Correct, I see what you are asking now.
My last edit should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to update them all not only one, plus please remember this is running in loop so you always do before and then after which I don't want

Comment: I think my latest edit should answer your question. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks but still this doesn't answer my question