# How to Request Website Pages Using Cookies [Python]

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get website data as if I were viewing it myself, ie: sending a request to google along with all my cookies to view my personal google settings page.

I tried doing something like this:

```
import requests as req
cookies = {
''' all my cookies here '''
}
print(req.get('https://google.com', cookies = cookies))
```

Sending this request shows me the page as if I were seeing the page from my own computer

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use cookies in Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554771/how-to-use-cookies-in-python-requests)