# Can I "transfer" session from reqeust.session to selenium.webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I use with reqeust.session and reqeust post to send some data to the server.
I want to transfer the session from the reqeust to selenium and after that open the selenium browser and continue to use.
Can I do it?

If there is option to load selenium browser and send POST reqeust and after that countiue use with the selenium browser its also option for me.

thanks

Comment: The session should be identified by a cookie, so you should be able to get cookie from the requests response https://stackoverflow.com/a/31555440/202168 and add it to the subsequent selenium requests https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058521/202168

Comment: thank you, I get the cookie from the reqeust session and its get like this "<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie PHPSESSID=h5j3amqvvlm7q36bnoh50guc07 for sneakerboxtlv.com/>, <Cookie woocommerce_cart_hash=0d7f21acee349574e94d3f79e920f75c for sneakerboxtlv.com/>, <Cookie woocommerce_items_in_cart=1 for sneakerboxtlv.com/>, <Cookie wp_woocommerce_session_baebb96204e6a0de4c6aed7ee1c9843d=t_1bd0c7ff33227c04c41926df5b47fa%7C%7C1655545100%7C%7C1655541500%7C%7Cc14d5428eb01147448fceb0a07721b45 for sneakerboxtlv.com/>]>" and the selenium load cookie need to be json... there is option to convert it?

Comment: So there are several cookies in the "cookie jar"... you may need to add all of them or just a subset.  See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/?highlight=cookies#cookies

Comment: not a good idea to post actual session cookies here... (hopefully that's not the case...)

Comment: easiest way to do this would be to set the webdriver to use a profile that has already logged in.  This may or may not contain session cookies.  It really depends on the site's implementation.