# Grabbing Cookie from Server with Python Requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I have been looking at the Requests documentation for a way to grab a site cookie for use elsewhere in my code. The documentation states the following:

```
If a response contains some Cookies, you can quickly access them:

>>> url = 'http://example.com/some/cookie/setting/url'
>>> r = requests.get(url)

>>> r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
'example_cookie_value'
```

I'm not sure however what would go inside the square brackets after `r.cookies`. If I try submitting with no square brackets at all I get the following output:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do with the above to get the actual cookies returned back to me, please?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

In response to the first comment below, here is some example code, which is returning an empty dictionary for the cookie. Can anyone tell me why?

```
import requests, requests.utils

r = requests.get('http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/?d=2015W32&isAggregate=false')
session = requests.session()
rr = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)
print rr
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13030095/1679863

Comment: please see my amended question above with the issue I am still experienceing after reading the link you provided.

Comment: You need to move `requests.session()` before the `get` call, and use `session.get()` instead of `requests.get()`

Answer (score 0):

The site you are trying to get cookies from does not appear to exist. If I substitute a different website in your code:

```
import requests, requests.utils

r = requests.get('http://google.com')  # using google.com
print(r.cookies.keys())
```

Output:

```
['NID']
```