# How can I save the Cookies of each session in Python?

Tags: python, cookies

How can I save session cookies in python?

I know I have to open a file like this

```
open('cookies.txt', "w")
```

but I don't know how to save the cookies for each session

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030095/how-to-save-requests-python-cookies-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

`file1 = open("myfile.txt","w")`

words need to be written inside the txt file

`L = ["HAI \n","Hello \n","How are you \n"]`

to write inside the txt file

`file1.writelines(L)`

close the text file

`file1.close()`