# What's the quickest, most hassle free way of fixing a virtualenv with screwy python marshalling?

Tags: python, marshalling, virtualenv, eof, corruption

The short of it is:

`from mega.capture_classes.class_wc_daemon import WCDaemon`

Gives me:

`EOFError: EOF read where not expected`

This all happened inside a virtualenv. And, yes, I made sure class_wc_daemon.py looks healthy.

Now I gather that this error is only thrown be Python marshalling, and that the best way to fix the error is re-installing Python (see [Python 3.2 won't import cookielib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857677/python-3-2-wont-import-cookielib)) My PC crashed in an interesting and colorful way so I think something got corrupted so this makes sense...

I've been googling around a whole lot and can't find a straight answer to my question:

What's the quickest, most hassle free way of fixing a virtualenv with screwy python marshalling?

I can just make a new virtualenv, copy over all my code, re-install all the packages and run with it but I'm sure there's a better way?

Comment: Python doesn't do any marshalling of itself. It *does* create byte-code cache files (`*.pyc` files). Perhaps you should clean those out? They'll be re-compiled as needed.

Comment: For future reports it would be very helpful if you include the full error including the backtrace instead of just the final line. Without that information it is often impossible to spot the problem source.

Comment: @WichertAkkerman: In this case it was not necessary. The background to the error was explained in full. The traceback said the import didn't work. Since this was the first line of the file that's all it said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was a corrupt .pyc file. I deleted all my pycs and got Python to make me some new ones and it all worked out great.

Thanks to Martjin Pieters for the comment - you are a scholar and a gentleman :)